# Why NO_MATCH system Google Assistant event is not triggered?

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I have the following setup of my Google Action -

**Types** - GAMEMODE:

- survival
- creative

**Intents** - CMD_SET_GAMEMODE:

- training phrases:

  - change game mode to creative
  - apply creative game mode

**Scenes** - COMMANDS:

- Custom intent handling

  - When CMD_ANOTHER_COMMAND is matched
  - When CMD_SET_GAMEMODE is matched - Transition to CMD_SET_GAMEMODE_SlotFilling

**Scenes** - CMD_SET_GAMEMODE_SlotFilling:

- Condition: if scene.slots.status == "FINAL" call my webhook
- Slot filling

  - gamemode: prompts for NO_MATCH - default values

Here is what happens when I test the dialog -

1. input `change game mode to survival` - works fine, my webhook is called
2. input `change game mode` - getting `Sorry, My Action isn't responding right now. Please try again soon.`
3. input `change game mode to something` - getting `Sorry, My Action isn't responding right now. Please try again soon.`
   When I check the log, I see that the error happens with `endConversation` event at `CMD_SET_GAMEMODE_SlotFilling` scene.

I don't understand why NO_MATCH prompts are not used?

Comment: It is a little difficult to follow just from the text description. Can you provide screen shots of the two scenes, with the slot descriptions expanded and possibly screen shots or copied text showing the commands that you're issuing and the debugging accompanying each?

Comment: From what I can tell, the "CMD_SET_GAMEMODE" is being called, but because the game mode type is not specified, it seems to run into some unexpected behavior. You may want to check for the type in your webhook and review [slot filling](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/scenes).